# React-Router Match-component does not trigger shouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app build on estejs (devstack), which uses react-router, I ran into the following problem:

`<Match pattern="/cards/:sub?" component={Cards}/>`

Matches `localhost:3000/cards` and `localhost:3000/cards/test` perfectly,
but does not call `shouldComponentUpdate()` as expected from the 
[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Since `:sub` is a parameter, it should just change the prop `this.props.params.sub` of the `card` component and because of that also call `shouldComponentUpdate()` where I then want to `return false` to denie the `render()`-call.

Why does the Match component not just update the prop but trigger a not denieable rerender of my component?
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Doc of react-router match component for further information: https://react-router.now.sh/Match

Comment: another thing: the constructor of the card component is called on every URL change. Seems like its re-created everytime?! Shouldnt it just update?